# Resolve Ember.create is deprecated in favor of Object.create

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to resolve deprecation warning.

How do we create new objects now?

Currently using this syntax -

```
var groupInfo = Ember.Object.create({
    groupedItems: value.content,
    group: Ember.computed('groupedItems', function(){
        return this.get('groupedItems').get('firstObject').get('group');
    })
});
```

Comment: You are not using Ember.create in the above code. You are using Ember.Object.create. Ember.create does what Object.create does in JavaScript, it creates an object with a prototype and properties. Ember uses it to be compatible with IE8. Your deprecation warning is likely coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Probably I need to upgrade ember-data...